# How to deal with clumsy agents harming themselves?

Tags: evil-genius

I have the following problem: my evil base is tip top but once in a while a pack of goobers with machine guns visit me and what they do is plant bomb to destroy a set of doors. After planting the bomb they camp that spot and blow themselves up catching fire.

What happens next they get angry, they receive 1 bar of heat (even though I haven't done a thing to harm them) and start shooting everyone in my base.

Is there any way to avoid it or executing them is the only thing I can do?

Great game but has some serious flaws.

Comment: Upvoted for the sheer hilarity of the situation :)

Comment: tried affecting their smarts with popup traps etc? also your social minions can interact with them in order to affect their stats, possibly making them forget they were ever there

Comment: If you have ample money, place an array of shacks across the island, each with a barracks (any room will do) and place a stat trap in there (i.e. popup trap). Not only will it delay, but they will likely set off multiple of these traps. (By using a barracks, you can also fit in a locker for additional minion space, a nice bonus)

Comment: Thanks for the great tips. I actually haven't used dummy traps thinking they raise heat (like the other traps). Will definitely try it out

Comment: I am not saying they are the best, but certainly they are the first of a long line of stat effecting traps (and quite possibly the cheapest?)

Answer (score 4):

The solution suggested in the comments is my go-to strategy for dealing with enemy agents.

The trick is to create a shack that has little or (ideally) no heat.  Put the best, highest security door you can on the shack, so that it takes a long time to crack.  Agents *love* these high-security doors.  Behind the door, make sure you have a Pop-up Trap to bewilder the invaders, plus a timeclock to keep your minions from working in the area.

If you have enough shacks, agents will waste all their time bouncing back and forth between picking all the locks until their stats are so drained they're effectively harmless and they go home.

Comment: I think I read this strategy on the Evil Genius wiki, but that site appears to be broken :(

Comment: Normal minions can't go through a level 4 door, so do you really need a timeclock?

Comment: By level 4, I'm referring to the bottom of the info panel.  Level 1 doors are unlocked, level 2 doors are locked but any base personnel can open them, level 3 doors are restricted to the Genius and his Henchman/bodyguard, level 4 doors are restricted to the Genius only.

Comment: @Powerlord, It's been forever since I did this, so my memory's likely a little off.  I seem to recall needing to occasionally let a Valet in to put fires out or someone to maintain the trap(s) inside the shack.  I think the timeclock also keeps the room unpowered, although I don't think the stuff you're likely to have inside the room needs power.  Maybe it was redundant?  I'll have to go back and play again to see :P

Answer (score 0):

This is OP.

Shacks with traps and fake entrance with traps are bad ideas. Why? They are great against low level burglars and investigators but when soldiers cannot open the doors they will start shooting them, then the doors explode, then soldiers aggro, then they kill everyone in your base. When soldiers see traps they also start shooting them at sight (donno why).

In the end how I managed it was: you need long entrance corridor with many doors in it as well as a lot of stuff that can explode, preferably traps but everything works, even lockers. Personally I build barracks instead of corridors and fill half of the passage with lockers (room saving FTW), occasionally I join them with 4x4 corridors to have place for fire extinguishers. I believe AI counts it as lots of different rooms with passages. Also passages with looping around are great idea, so everything in shape of 8 works, agents wonder around never actually getting past the mess hall.

I have some traps set in it against burglars and investigators. When soldiers break in I change alarm to yellow and switch the doors in corridor to lvl 3, otherwise minions run to soldiers 1 by 1 trying to solo them (AI in this game...). So, at the moment I have pack of soldiers trying to force their way into my base.

I wait for the soldiers to cripple themselves by destroying random objects on the way, when they reach last door I switch the alarm to red and let my armed guards/minions do the job, usually they are stack so dense there is no problem with killing 4-6 soldiers (with minimal casualties ofc).

Ofc if soldiers don't aggro and I manage to calm them down with my army of valets before those retards harm themselves and blame it on me it's even better.

I believe I have constructed perfect base on first island. There are a lot of things to keep in mind in this game (mostly because of lack of logic). I had to reset 3 times to get myself going well. Game can be completed without traps, it's even easier than with traps. Clever base design is the most important. At the beginning my biggest mistake was make corridors and join heat rooms to it- WRONG. Much better to create some low heat room, and one corridor that leads from it to the heat part of the base, rest is like regular business.